# What layout should i use to create something like in the sample?

Tags: android, android-layout

Okay.I'm still new to android and I'm developing a weather app for my final year project. It should function like the one in the sample where there is a list view and when the user click one of the bar it will open a detail view about that tab in the same page(or do people call it fragment? i don't know). So when the user open the detail view the other tab should go downward.Thanks in advance.

[image: Sample UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using `Expandable List View` you can achieve this.**

Below reference links.

https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/ExpandableHeightListView

http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) to accomplish that functionality.